# DataStax OpsCenter - can't connect with agents

Tags: cassandra, nosql, opscenter

I've installed DataStax OpsCenter (Apache Cassandra) and in OpsCenter, there is an error: "0 of 1 agents connected". When I click "fix", enter credentials and try to install nodes, i get error:

> Unable to SSH to some of the hosts
>
> Unable to SSH to 127.0.0.1: global name 'get_output' is not defined

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue in a Windows 7 64-bit installation of Opscenter 5.0.0. Turns out the user needed to have local administrator rights on the PC. Adding the user account resolved this issue for me.